# Jenkins - Dynamic Choice Parameter - Removing File extension from list

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am having a bit of trouble getting my groovy code to work properly in Jenkins using the Dynamic choice parameter. We currently have a folder that contains a lot of properties files for various environments. The following groovy code returns a list of all the file names correctly, however it is appending the file extension which is unneeded.

```
    Arrays.asList(new File("path").list())
```

How would I change that to only list .xml files and not append the file extension in the list. I've found some examples of this while searching, but for some reason when I try some of these examples it isn't populating the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like:

```
new File( 'path' ).list()
                  .findAll { it.endsWith( '.xml' ) }
                  .collect { it[ 0..-5 ] }
```

That gets the list of files (as Strings), keeps those that end with `.xml`, then removes the .xml off the end

Comment: Perfect! I tried something similar and it wasn't working properly. Must have missed something. Thanks